# Explain the double sum step by step

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm looking at the following:

[image]

But when I try to reproduce the result, I get: For $n=1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{i} (i+1)(j+1)$$

$$= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i + 1) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{i} (j+1)$$

$$= \sum_{i=0}^{1} (i + 1) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{1} (j+1)$$

$$= \left((0+1)+ \sum_{i=1}^{1} (i + 1)\right) \cdot \left((0+1) + \sum_{j=1}^{1}(j+1)\right)$$

$$= \big(1 + (1 + 1)\big) \cdot \big(1 + (1+1)\big)$$

$$= 3 \cdot 3$$

$$= 9$$
Please, explain what is wrong with my solution

Comment: If you look at how this works, it's like adding the rows of a multiplication table, with $n=0$ yielding $1$, $n=1$ yielding $1+2+4$, $n=2$ yielding $1+2+4+3+6+9$ and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This double sum is not a product of two individual sums, but it is an inner sum nested inside an outer sum. Concretely, you face up a sum $$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i,$$ whose elements are themselves defined by a sum, more precisely $$a_i = (i+1) \sum_{j=0}^i (j+1).$$ Given that the inner sum depends on the index of the outer one, you cannot separate and treat them freely. When $n = 1$, you end up with $S_1 = a_0 + a_1$, with $$a_0 = (0 + 1) \sum_{j=0}^0 (j+1) = 1 \cdot (0+1) = 1$$ and $$a_1 = (1 + 1) \sum_{j=0}^1 (j+1) = 2 \cdot ((0+1) + (1+1)) = 6,$$ hence $S_1 = 7$ in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- You seem to have moved the $j$ sum out of the $i$ sum incorrectly.  Where you write $$\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^i (j+1)  \text{,}$$ you actually have $$\sum_{i=0}^n \left( (i+1) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^i (j+1) \right)  \text{,}$$ which is not a product of two disentangled sums.
- This leaves you with a problem in your next line -- since you interpret the $j$ sum as outside the $i$ sum, you don't know what to use for your upper index in the $j$ sum.  What you write gives a product of four terms, when $(i,j)$ are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$.  However, in the original sum, when $i = 0$, $j$ only ranges over $[0,i]=[0,0]$.  That is, the $(0,1)$ term is not present in the original but appears in your sum when you have to pick an upper index that doesn't mention $i$.  This extra term is a $2$, which makes your sum $2$ units too big.